Насколько широко применим вопросительный знак?
1
Вопросительным знаком заканчиваются предложения, выражающие вопрос. Но в сети встречаются употребления, где им обозначена интонация сомнения:

Я так думаю?

Передавая примерно такой смысл: "Я так думаю", - с сомнением сказал он, пожав плечами.
То есть, это не вопрос: "Думаю ли я так?", а интонация.
Допустимо ли применение вопросительного знака таким образом?
2
Встречаются и такие случаи применения:

Мне сказали, вы хотели меня видеть?
Он спросил, какой сегодня день?

На мой взгляд, эти предложения не являются вопросами. "Мне сказали, что вы хотели меня видеть", - это не вопрос, а утверждение. Вопросом было бы: "Сказали ли мне, что вы хотели меня видеть?"
Аналогично: "Он спросил, какой сегодня день", - это утверждение и поэтому, на мой взгляд, предложение должно заканчиваться точкой.
Иначе смысл получается другой: "Спросил ли он, какой сегодня день?"
Но в сети такое употребление приводится как верное:

Если вопросительное предложение является частью более крупного предложения, то вопросительный знак ставится только в конце полного предложения. Пример: «Он спросил, какой сегодня день?»

https://obzorposudy.ru/polezno/cto-znacit-rasstav-znaki-prepinaniya#kak-pravilno-rasstavit-voprositelnyy-znak
На мой взгляд, тут вопросительный знак требовал бы оформления прямой речи:

Он спросил: «Какой сегодня день?»

Что говорят об этом авторитетные источники? или есть разные мнения?
Итак, вот два варианта, о которых я спрашиваю:

Ставится ли вопросительный знак для выражения сомнения в предложении, которое ни по форме, ни по сути вопросом не является?

(Я думаю, нет?)

Ставится ли вопросительный знак в конце предложения, содержащего вопрос, но в целом вопросом не являющимся?

(Я спросил, как?)
Насколько я понял, возможны разные взгляды:

В истории русской пунктуации по вопросу о её основах и назначении выделились три основных направления: логическое, синтаксическое и интонационное.
Представители интонационной теории полагают, что знаки препинания служат для обозначения ритмики и мелодики фразы (Л. В. Щерба), что в большинстве случаев отражают не грамматическое, а декламационно-психологическое расчленение речи (А. М. Пешковский).

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Пунктуация#Интонационное_направление
Получается, это на усмотрение автора текста?

Понятно, что в чатиках писать мона кахугодна. Я интересуюсь "регулярным" правописанием: в текстах книг (помимо искажений для речевой характеристики персонажа) и т.п.


Я бы сказал, что здесь вопросительный знак здесь ставится только в том случае, если это действительно вопрос:


– Вы хотите, чтобы я Вам грубил? Думаю, нет. [= Сильно сомневаюсь.]

Фактически, говорящий сам даёт ответ на вопрос, не давая собеседнику времени подумать.

– Вы хотите, чтобы я Вам грубил? Думаю, нет? [= Ведь не хотите?]

Говорящий больше вовлекает собеседника в беседу, как бы приглашая самому обдумать ответ, хотя вопрос всё равно остаётся риторическим, просто интонация добавляет эмоциональной окраски.

Вот здесь есть параграф 2.4, к которому есть примечание:


Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения образует
косвенный вопрос, то в конце предложения вопросительный знак обычно не
ставится: Я прервал речь Савельина вопросом, сколько у меня всего
денег (П.); Корчагин неоднократно спрашивал меня, когда он может
выписаться (Н.О.).
Однако если косвенный вопрос содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную
интонацию, в конце сложноподчиненного предложения вопросительный знак
ставится: Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за огни? (Л.Т.); Я спросил, как
же он стал отшельником? (М.Г.)

Это подтверждает Ваше предположение, что постановка знака здесь зависит от автора. При этом первый пример некорректен, как по мне. "Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за огни?" – это "честный" вопрос.
Кстати, беглый опрос двух десятков коллег показал, что предложение "Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником" ~95 процентов опрошенных закончили бы точкой.

Я считаю, это сильно зависит от области применения текста.
Кавычки должны употребляться и снять двусмысленность, если речь идёт про любой текст, адресованный широкой аудитории: статья научная или журнальная, книга, информационное сообщение-тема на форуме. Неряшливо написанный текст понижает доверие к источнику, особенно бумажному. Хотя без сомнения встречается и такое.
С другой стороны, если мы говорим о личной переписке в мессенджере или чате на несколько активных участников, и даже отдельной реплике на форуме: сложно ожидать от участников, что они будут следить за пунктуацией и писать "для вечности". От них даже больших букв и вопросительных знаков самих по себе не всегда дождёшься. В этой ситуации даже Он спросил, какой сегодня день? вполне допустимо, причём в зависимости от контекста обсуждения равно допустимы оба применения: Как "спросил ли он это", так и "вот что он спросил".

Видела я как-то раз в Рунете очень странный вопрос, представляющий собой смесь заумных научных терминов и обычных слов. Обычные слова были написаны с чудовищными ошибками, словно писал 7-летний ребенок. В ответ кто-то опубликовал издевательский текст, представляющий собой смесь высокоинтеллектуальных фраз и фраз в стиле гопника. Одной из фраз гопника было: "брателло, давай с тобой дружить?"
То есть неуместное использование вопросительного знака уже стало мемом.

В моём понимании, "давай дружить?" - это вопрос, поэтому здесь вопросительный знак не вызвает у меня вспышки красного света.
